# HTML editors for DNN

Tags: telerik, ckeditor, dotnetnuke, fckeditor, radeditor

I need a html editor because the one provided by DNN 6 is not working. The radeditor wont display sub folders or images that i have copied from the file system to the DNN portal installation. The document manager also doesnt work and just shows up as white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this blog post from Will Strohl helps address your issue.

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/3021/No-Folders-in-DotNetNuke-RadEditor-Image-Manager.aspx

Comment: Im afraid Telerik provider wont work with DNN6 - that is the first thing i tried because its perfect in DNN 5.6